# How to properly render a partial template that is using a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and the jquery-rails 2.0.2 gem (including the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) plugin). In order to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) my code I am planning to "extract" the [jQuery Dialog Widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog) in a partial template that will be rendered in my application almost the same way; so, I am thinking to implement and render that template by passing some "complex" code (possibly, JavaScript code) throughout the [`:locals`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) statement... but I have some trouble on how to properly pass that code.

Specifically, I would like to render the template by passing `:locals` *with which "build"* / *that "populate"* some jQuery Dialog *Option*, *Event*, *Method* (see the [jQuery UI Official Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog) for more information) as-like, for example, the option `title` or the event `close` (*note*: it is intended that the "passed" / "builded" / "populated" content is JavaScript code or both JavaScript and Ruby code).

What / how could / should I make to accomplish what I aim to make? Is there some "common" approach or practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example. See if this is helpful, and YMMV.

A partial can contain JavaScript and Ruby code as ERB (or HAML, or whatever templating you want to use).

I use the convention of putting shared partials in the directory `./app/views/shared`.

Example file `./app/views/shared/_dialog.html.erb`:

```
<!-- typical jQuery dialog box creator -->
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
</script>

<!-- typical dialog with Ruby ERB for title and message -->
<div id="dialog" title="<%= title %>">
  <p><%= message %></p>
</div>
```

To call the partial from your view page:

```
<h1>My Page</h1>
<%= render :partial => "shared/dialog",
    :locals => { :title => :"Hello", :message => "World" } %>
```

Comment: I already know that you said (it is present in the Official Documentations linked in the question *!*). In my case I am looking for passing with `:locals` (and properly "build" the rendered template) a "combination" of JavaScript and Ruby code to a partial template.